# How to edit MS Word .xsl style documents to remove parens

Tags: ms-word, xls, bibliography, citations

I'm using Word 2017 and need to remove parentheses from my citations so instead of looking like "(Author, YYYY)" they look like "Author, YYYY". It's a book manuscript, so lots of citations, so I need something global. I don't want to do any of this manually.

My web search led me to [these instructions](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/turnoff-parantheses-in-apa-citation.4013302/) which describe editing the APA.xsl file, which looks like exactly what I need. The Word 2017 equivalent appears to be APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl. I made the edits in the link but my changes aren't having any affect. The file is in "..\Office16\Bibliography\Style" which I think is correct. As a test, I removed all of the .xsl files out of this folder and it didn't seem to have any affect, so I'm not surprised my edits aren't taking. I'm at a bit of a loss, so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my main problem. [This site](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/change_the_type_of_brackets_in_citations.html) suggested I was editing the wrong files, and should be working in

```
 C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style\, where *** is your user name
```

The only other tweak was described [here](https://thomasplagwitz.com/2014/09/14/ho-to-get-square-brackets-and-hide-comments-with-iso690-with-word-2013-bibliography-style/) that MS Word 2013 onward uses *StyleNameLocalized* instead of *StyleName* (the original link I posted was great, but a bit out of date.)

Summarizing, the main steps for removing brackets in Word 2013+ is

1. Copy and rename the .xsl file (to preserve the original) in your C:\Users\ ... \Style folder
2. Search for the *StyleNameLocalized* tags and edit their values (there's lots, but you can just find the one you use).

E.g.,

```
<xsl:when test="b:StyleNameLocalized/b:Lcid='1033'">
    <xsl:text>APA</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
```

becomes

```
<xsl:when test="b:StyleNameLocalized/b:Lcid='1033'">
    <xsl:text>APA No Brackets</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
```

3. Per the original link, find and remove the two blocks that add the brackets:

open bracket block:

```
<xsl:if
test="msxsl:node-set($ListPopulatedWithMain)/b:Citation/b:FirstAuthor">
<xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_OpenBracket"/>
</xsl:if>
```

closed bracket block:

```
<xsl:if test="/b:Citation/b:LastAuthor">
<xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_CloseBracket"/>
</xsl:if>
```

You can then select the entire document and apply the new citation style